# Regex match issue with \d* and |

Tags: python, regex

I have two regex to parse some information  in python

1. `(block|tower|building|wing)\s*[-]*\s*(\d* |[A-Za-z]{1,3})`
2. `(block|tower|building|wing)\s*[-]*\s*(\d*|[A-Za-z]{1,3})`

Notice the missing space after **`\d*`** . The first one matches the string **block A** but the second  one does not. I am not able to understand what is wrong in the second one ?

Comment: `\d*` matches an empty string so the `[A-Za-z]{1,3}` is never tried as `\d*` *always* matches, either digits or an empty string before a non-matching char. `(\d*|[A-Za-z]{1,3})` = `(\d*)`. Use `\d+` instead, or swap the alternatives.

Comment: Yes it does (see https://regex101.com/r/NbnZHq/1), but the second group is empty because of the `\d*` which means, zero or more digits. `\d*` matches an empty string (**zero** or more).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks changed from * to + .